# How to use order by with table to sort the table in hierarchical way

Tags: sql-server

I am given with table shown in Image 1

[image]

How to use order by statement so that i can get resultant table. I don't know how to solve it. I just try to use order by C, D column but all numm comes upwards irrespective of B Column.

Result given in image 2

[image]

---

Updated

Sorry, I just forgot to mention this table also contain id and this table is already sorted on the basis of id. So i am not even able to sort it by column A. Due to this SQL think whole table is already sorted but I still want to sort on the basis of column

Comment: Please don't post images of data. Data is textual and should be posted as `text`. What attempts have you made to try to get your expected result set? Can you explain the logic to get from "A to B" please when you post your attempt(s) as well please? Thanks,

Comment: ORDER BY A, B, C, D ?

Comment: hi i think you can try order by A, B, C, D

Comment: You need to try the suggestions.... `Order By A,B,C,D` Data is always returned according to the order by statement. Tables are not pre-ordered